# Azure event hub service

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-eventhub

1. How to handle exception in event hub
2. if event hub it self down
3. if event retention period over and if we want to send same event again

Any idea or hit how to handle this situations for event hub.
Any sample code or settings help needed

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please elaborate more about item 3 "if event retention period over and if we want to send same event again"?

Comment: 1. Determine how expired events can be replayed (if needed)
2. How to handle version
3. What happens if event hub is down

Answer (score 1):

1. Please take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-messaging-exceptions#:%7E:text=Exception%20types%20%20%20%20Exception%20Type%20,add%20retr%20...%20%208%20more%20rows%20) doc for exceptions and how to handle them. In general, client should retry transient exceptions. On the other hand, non-transient exceptions require manual intervention most of the times.
2. Azure Event Hubs provides a highly available stream processing service. For even higher availability I suggest you you to look at 'zone redundancy' and 'paired namespaces' features.
3. Unless it is a system requirement there is nothing wrong with sending the same message. Please note that retention period is a consumer side feature, it has no impact for producers.

Comment: Hello, Team. Thanks for suggestions 1. Any one have same code for exception handling in producer end 2.  Is their any dead letter queue  to add message after certain period to re send again. 3. When we capture events in blob container its storing .avro format can we change fomat to json while capture?